# jquery prevent default questions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I get preventDefault to operate properly in this context? If the user clicks the hyper link the page reloads, I'm looking to prevent this default action. Generally I would catch a click event or something, but I'm calling a function directly from a hyper link. I'm not sure how to do it this way. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<a href='' onclick="javascript:OpenModal(<?=$val->Prodid;?>);"><?=$val->ProdDesc;?>

<script>
function OpenModal(id) {
    OpenModal.preventDefault(); //this does not work, but is here to show what I'm trying to do.
    $.ajax({
        url: "?url=Inventory/detail/"+id,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#divDetail').html(data);
            $('#divDetail').dialog({
                modal: true,
                width: 'auto'
            });

        },  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('error'.textStatus.errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

if I add:

```
 <a href='' onclick="javascript:OpenModal(<?=$val->Prodid;?>); return false;"><?=$val->ProdDesc;?>
```

it works properly, but I'd imagine this is sort of a hack instead of the proper way of doing things.
Thoughts?

Comment: the proper way currently is to not use inline events. Why not just give it an id and add an event listener and use preventDefault()?

Comment: Not recommended to use php's short open and close tag, oh no.

Comment: @edward - actually, that anti short tag trend has passed. It's now accepted as though that attack never happened.

Comment: @edward I thought short tags like <? were not recommended but for echoing out data <?= was fine. Is this not the case?

Comment: It has to be enabled in your php ini file, if it is disabled (ie if you upgrade your version of php or uploaded it to a server where they were disabled) you could have to go through your whole script again. http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: @KaiQing just going by the manual

Comment: Well i have learnt something new today! I apologies profusely and will be using them in my scripts from now on! :-) http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass in the `event` object and call `preventDefault()` on that:

```
 <a href='' onclick="javascript:OpenModal(<?=$val->Prodid;?>, event);"><?=$val->ProdDesc;?>


function OpenModal(id, event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: reminder to OP - `javascript:` is superfluous in onclick properties. `onclick="OpenModal()"` would work too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a data attr to parse your id to JQuery and bind the event to a click function then do preventDefault on that.

## HTML

```
<a href='#' id='myLink' data-value='<?php echo $myVal; ?>'>Click Me!</a>
```

## JQuery

```
$('#myLink').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    OpenModal( $(this).attr('data-value') );

});

function OpenModal(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "?url=Inventory/detail/"+id,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#divDetail').html(data);
            $('#divDetail').dialog({
                modal: true,
                width: 'auto'
            });

        },  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('error'.textStatus.errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the event, you can do it in the event itself if you declare it too

```
<script>
 $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {  
  event.preventDefault();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this affect the way my other hyper links work though?

Comment: You could give the a an id or a name and set the event for that (like a name noDefaultAction)